# How to call WordPress function other files

Tags: plugins, php, wp-query, functions

Hi All i am in word Press

I have successfully integrated WordPress membership plugin and all data of users is saved in database.  Different users have different levels.

My major task is to disable some website button according to user levels. so i try to Get user id in report.php using

```
require_once("/wp-load.php");
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

**But it gives internal 500 error**
my directry structure is 
/myproject/wp-content/themes/fount/myfolder/report.php

Comment: where do you put your file? and also rember to check if your user is logged in with: `is_user_logged_in()`

Comment: @Mederic my files are in themes folders

Comment: If your files are in the themes folders, then `require_once("/wp-load.php");` is incorrect. Use the correct path.

Comment: @Otto wp-load.php is my myproject folder which is root folder of our PROJECT

Comment: here is my directory structure can you guide more
 /myproject/wp-content/themes/fount/myfolder/

Comment: i update my question 
i am calling   function  (is_user_logged_in) using report.php

which is in  /myproject/wp-content/themes/fount/myfolder/report.php

Comment: it's not recommanded to use a direct acces to a PHP file. use instead AJAX (https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) or REST (https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/)

Comment: Maybe you should put the code into the `functions.php` of your active theme (_/wp-content/themes/folder-of-theme/functions.php_). This file is included with every request, so you don't have to require `wp-load.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that *wp-load* is in the folder **/myproject/** of your `/myproject/wp-content/themes/fount/myfolder/` tree.

From **/myfolder/** you would access it with `"../../../../wp-load.php".`